# HBase region server cannot connect with master

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, cygwin, hbase

I have configured HBase-0.98.6.1 in Windows using Cygwin from [here](http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html) and hadoop-2.5.1 is installed. For running HBase in fully distributed mode, I am following [this](http://jayatiatblogs.blogspot.in/2013/01/hbase-installation-fully-distributed.html).

I want to run HBase in fully distribute mode with 2 region servers.

**Clustering setup**

- master, regionserver1 - local machine
- regionserver2 - remote machine1

**External Zookeepers**

- zookeeper1 - remote machine2
- zookeeper2 - remote machine3

Before a week I could run HBase without any problem. 
But today, I am having problem with regionserver2 connecting to HMaster. regionserver1(local machine) can connect with HMaster, but regionserver2 fails.

**Exception**

> 2014-11-06 11:46:16,144 INFO  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty to master=synclapn3382,60000,1415254568454 with port=60020, startcode=1415254574190
>   2014-11-06 11:46:16,248 WARN  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up
>   com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: no further information
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1678)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1719)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.RegionServerStatusProtos$RegionServerStatusService$BlockingStub.regionServerStartup(RegionServerStatusProtos.java:8277)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:2102)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:857)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: no further information
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClient.java:578)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClient.java:868)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.getConnection(RpcClient.java:1543)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1442)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1661)
>       ... 5 more
>   2014-11-06 11:46:16,249 WARN  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty failed; sleeping and then retrying.

I have assigned host names in **/etc/hosts** file correctly. I can ping the master IP from command prompt. I don't understand why this exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled rDNS? regionserver2 is trying to connect to "synclapn3382" which is you master name. I would try to ping from rs2 to master using that hostname to check if it can reach it.

Comment: You shouldn't answer a question with another question. This belongs in the comment section

Comment: I could ping from both of the system.

Comment: telnet synclapn3382 60020?